# How would I go about writing tests for Sharepoint Webparts?

Tags: node.js, typescript, sharepoint, web-parts, ts-jest

How would I go about Unit Testing CRUD methods in a Sharepoint webpart? I've tried following the Jest documentation in regards to creating Mock of classes / specific methods, but I don't think its possible given that the service class that I'm supposed to be testing, requires a specific Context for the constructor.

```
export default class PnpServices implements IPnpServices {
private _sp;
constructor(context: WebPartContext) {
    this._sp = getSP(context);
}

public async sp_createItem(listName: string, itemObject: any): Promise<any> {
    try {
        const iar: IItemAddResult = await this
        ._sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName).items.add(itemObject)
        return iar.data.Id;
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error("error")
    }
}
```

I tried setting up a simple test to check if the Constructor could even be called when parsing "null" as an argument instead of a context

```
    jest.mock('./pnpservices')
it('should pass', () => {
    const mockedClassInstance = new PnpServices(null);
    expect(PnpServices).toBeCalledTimes(1);
})
```

Most examples I can find dont create actual genuinely useful tests or even have business-oriented methods such as CRUD, theyre mostly just simple "addition" methods or their only functionality is returning a console.log.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy with SPFx web parts. First, jest itself is not out of the box, and tou have a lot of stuff to install and configure. I followed this article, it worked more or less a few years ago:

https://www.eliostruyf.com/sharepoint-framework-unit-tests-with-jest/

Since you seem to also be using pnpjs in the same project, you might want to check this out:

https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/1425

Comment: I've tried following these tutorials, but I get the error "Unexpected Token 'Export'"

Comment: Well, there is no easy way as far as I can tell ) "unexpected token export" most probably means some library version incompatibility (from the used libraries)